# Removing words which are common to strings present in two lists

Tags: python, list

I have two list of strings

```
data_1 = ['The art is performed by james john.', 'art is quite silent']
data_2 = ['The art is performed by  hans.', 'art is very quite silent']
```

I want to remove common words from strings present in list and return two separate lists

```
result_1 = ['james john','']
result_2 = ['hans', 'very']
```

I tried this way

```
print([' '.join(set(i.split()).difference(set(data_1))) for i in data_2])
```

How to obtain a result like result_1 and result_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using numpy's `setdiff1d` function. Like:

```
difference_1 = [" ".join(list(np.setdiff1d(np.array(x.split()), np.array(y.split())))) for x, y in zip(data_1, data_2)]
```

Using `set.diference()` also should work:

```
difference_1 = [" ".join(set(x.split()).difference(set(z.split()))) for x, z in zip(data_1, data_2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

First tokenize the sentences using nltk

```
from nltk import word_tokenize


def list_tokenize(data):
    return [word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in data]
```

then get the common words

```
def get_common_words(data_1_tokenized,data_2_tokenized):
    return [
        list(set.intersection(set(sentence_1), set(sentence_2)))
        for sentence_1, sentence_2 in zip(data_1_tokenized, data_2_tokenized)
    ]
```

Then remove the common words

```
def remove_common_words(data, common_words):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        result.append(
            " ".join([word for word in data[i] if word not in common_words[i]]))
    return result
```

Combined function to get unique words

```
def get_unique(data_1,data_2):
    data_1_tokenized = list_tokenize(data_1)
    data_2_tokenized = list_tokenize(data_2)
    common_words = get_common_words(data_1_tokenized,data_2_tokenized)
    result1 = remove_common_words(data_1_tokenized,common_words)
    result2 = remove_common_words(data_2_tokenized,common_words)
    return result1,result2
```

final usage

```
data_1 = ['The art is performed by james john.', 'art is quite silent']
data_2 = ['The art is performed by  hans.', 'art is very quite silent']
result1,result2 = get_unique(data_1,data_2)
```

Results

result1=['james john', '']

result2=['hans', 'very']